# AWS Lambda fails with "Runtime.Unknown" in VPC with service endpoint for AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I've have to move a AWS Lambda function into a VPC because we have a RDS proxy running in there. The problem is that after I've put the Lambda into the VPC it always times out with the error `Error Type: Runtime.Unknown`.

I've setup a service endpoint for AWS Lambda for a single subnet in a single AZ. And, I've placed the function in the same.

Because, I don't get any further information it's quite hard to debug as the underlying technology of AWS Lambda is somehow a black box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I'm fetching a secret on the top level on my code and did have a service endpoint for it setup.

It seems that AWS Lambda is throwing the `Runtime.Unknown` error in case something went wrong on the root level during initialization.

Example:

```js
thisThrowsAnError();

export function yourActualHandler() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate here? I'm trying to debug this same error code for myself and I'm looking for _anything_...

Comment: @GusBus I'm using SST as the infrastructure framework for my application. And it is resolving the secrets at the root level of the code. So before your actual function code (e.g.: `export function handle()`) it is communicating the the SecretsManager. Bus this threw a silent error which caused the `Runtime.Unknown` error. I recommend starting with commenting out all imports and start import them again step by step to figure out if one of your imports is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks @floriangosse!!

We ended up getting to the bottom of it by fixing one of our imports too. In our case it was an MUI icon. These breadcrumbs led us to the solution: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44321 https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/117t880/nextjs_hosted_on_vercel_504_gateway_timeout/